# extend Stringbuilder to append array

Tags: c#, append, extension-methods, stringbuilder

Still new to the extension methods. According to this [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx), it is still unclear to me how I can append an array just like appending a string with Append(). Can anyone provide me with a small example?

```
int a  = 2;
object obj = XXXXX;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(a);
sb.Append(obj);
```

Basically the type of obj is unknown it could be int[], char[]..., I am trying to reuse Append() to make it more generalized to handle array types so the

```
sb.ToString()
```

will output the whole thing I have appended

Comment: @Nofuzy How is this a duplicate?

Comment: @user1935724 what are you trying to achieve, can you give an example?

Comment: @user1935724 I added a extension method.

Comment: @Nofuzy why don't you show me your answer before you think it's a duplicate that I can refer my answer to a so called "duplicate" and downvoting?

Comment: @user1935724 I did not downvote your question, you didn't post any code so I think it was duplicate, now I give you a Up vote ;)